# I have made an AdLoader.java Class which is not working.How do I access ads in android if I made a separate AdLoader.java Class in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, admob

The AdLoader.java

```
public class AdLoader {

    public InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    public InterstitialAd wInterstitialAd;
    public static AdLoader adLoader;

    public static AdLoader getAds() {

        if (adLoader == null) {
            adLoader = new AdLoader();
        }
        return adLoader;
    }


    public void loadFullAdmob(Context context) {
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(context.getString(R.string.admob_unit_id));

        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }

    public void showAdmob(Activity activity) {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
        }
        loadFullAdmob(activity);
    }

}
```

I am getting error alert on this line:

```
 mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
```

Probably an issue with context which I do not know how to fix.

I also have this in MainActivity.java

```
 AdLoader.getAds().loadFullAdmob(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void loadInterstitialAds(Activity context) {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    InterstitialAd.load(context, "INTERSTITIAL_ID", adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd ad) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
            ad.show(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
            Log.i(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());

}
```

use this latest code [Check this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJUxEjHtblE)